# Is it okay to wire an MCU output to an MCU input on the same chip?

Tags: microcontroller

My dsPIC33F does not seem to support routing the comparator to the input capture module. Would it be okay to run a wire from the comparator output to the input capture input?

I'm using a [dsPIC33FJ128GP802](http://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/Devices.aspx?dDocName=en532298).

Comment: Please, put a link to the datasheet.

Comment: I think this should apply for all dsPIC33F's but I've included a link to the product page anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did something quite similar for a PIC16F690 with no problems.

For that PIC, it could use the comparator output internally to trigger an interrupt, but there was a note indicating that there's a small window where the comparator can miss the interrupt.  In the end, I connected the comparator's output to an Interrupt-On-Change pin to make sure that I would always get an interrupt.

Comment: Yeah, I want to measure pulse width from the comparator. Thanks for your note of experience.

Comment: i'd toss a series resistor on the signal just to be safe

Comment: I agree with Mark. Nothing worse then accidentally managing to pull a pin when you didn't mean to causing stuff to over-current.

Comment: Maybe it's OK for PICs, but the question is about MCUs in general. For a counterexample the FEZ (.NET based MCU devboards) manual contains the following:

 "Important note: Never connect two output pins together. If they are connected and one is 
set to high and the other is set to low, you will damage the processor. Always connect an 
output pin to an input, driving circuit or a simple load like an LED."

It may be ok until you (accidentally or not) change the both ports to output, but then... So use current limiting resistor as Mark said, just to be sure.

Answer (score 5):

It's not just possible, it's darn useful.

All pins are inputs on power up.

Commonly used by embedded software guys like me to give a interrupt from a GPIO.

Who says there's no software interrupt instruction ?

Comment: "Who says there's no software interrupt instruction?" is the kind of humor I cannot get pure software or hardware guys to understand.

Comment: I've found myself frequently wiring controller pins together, wondering all the while why the designers insisted on segregating functionality as they did.  For example, is there any reason why one wouldn't want a processor to be able to query the state of an interrupt-request pin?

Comment: @Kortuk: that's because there *are*, or at least were, processors with a software interrupt. Take the SWI instruction in late MC6809, for instance.

Answer (score 1):

Provided the processor doesn't set them both as outputs during reset (most unlikely, and probably not very harmful in real life anyway), then you'll be fine.

Comment: Every PIC I've ever seen configures all GPIO pins as inputs on power-up.

Comment: Yes, quite.  I was just too lazy to go and look at the datasheet for that particular part.  Every time I guess what common-sense thing a modern micro is going to do with its I/O I get it wrong...

Comment: On that note, you may or may not want to be careful about adding a pull-up/-down resistor to that trace.  When the device comes up with both GPIO as inputs, it will be floating and this may or may not cause problems.